# Request state size is exceeds the threshold limit in Mendix

Tags: web, request, requesthandler, mendix

Request state size of 37449 objects exceeds the threshold of 100 objects. Request details: type 'RequestHandlingUtilImpl$' in session '34483ca1-e282-4938-868e-b4f4c76e4084'. State consists of:

- AdministrationModule.DashboardPageMetric (NPE): 1 objects
- AdministrationModule.QueuedApplicant (NPE): 37446 objects
- AdministrationModule.RowManager (NPE): 1 objects
- WebPushNotifications.NotificationPromptHelper (NPE): 1 objects

Answer (score 0):

Please phrase your question to contain an actual question.

Also take a look at the Mendix documentation regarding [Non-Persistable Objects and Garbage Collecting](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/transient-objects-garbage-collecting/) as it will explain that objects will be sent to the client with the response to a request. If the request state size grows too large look at:

> When the request state exceeds the configured threshold, you can look at the following list of possible causes (or a combination of them):
>
> - A problem in a widget (for example, if the widget does not unsubscribe itself from updates on objects which it showed previously)
> - Too many objects are associated with the current session or user
> - Non-persistable objects are associated with an object shown in a widget in a layout (meaning that this object stays in use as long as this layout is shown, usually a long time)